# Obtaining OpenGL ES Native Source from Android Open Source Project

Tags: android, opengl-es, native, android-source

I want to obtain the *native* Android implementation source files for OpenGL ES 3.0. The reason is so I can better understand the underlying OpenGL system as Android has implemented and to see precisely what each method is doing. GLES30 reference is fairly sparse. Also, looking at the GLES30 class source shows all methods as native. How do I see these methods' native code, specifically?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL ES itself will be implemented in the libraries provided by the GPU provider in the platform; most of these are proprietary and binary only. The AOSP code you have linked above is just the binding layer which calls into those native binaries, so I'm not sure how useful it is likely to be.

Comment: I see, I guess I am looking for a conceptual guide.

Comment: Also, in libagl/array.cpp I see those calls. The methods are pretty informative for seeing simply what they do.

Answer (score 0):

So, I believe this is to be the browsable implementation code for Android's OpenGL ES:

http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/native/opengl/